# DeleteFeature without click

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs-t, map-drawing

```
controlPoint = function (feature) {
                        alert(feature);
                        pointNumber = 1;
                        draw.deactivate();
                        noktasil(feature);

                    };
                     draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
                        wfs_layer, OpenLayers.Handler.Point, 
                        {
                            title: "Draw Feature",
                            displayClass: "olControlDrawFeaturePolygon",

                            multi: true,

                        }
                        );
                     draw.events.register("featureadded", ' ', controlPoint);
```

That's my codes  for creating new feature, it works. But i want to delete feature without click. And as you can see,  i store feature which i create and send it for deleting.

```
function noktasil(feature) {
                    // if feature doesn't have a fid, destroy it
                    var sil = new DeleteFeature(wfs_layer, { title: "Delete Feature" });
                    sil.noktasil(feature);

                }

                //set up the modification tools
                var DeleteFeature = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
                    initialize: function (layer, options) {
                        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]);
                        this.layer = layer;
                        this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Feature(
                            this, layer, { click: this.clickFeature }
                        );
                    },
                    noktasil: function (feature) {
                        // if feature doesn't have a fid, destroy it

                        if (feature.fid == undefined) {
                            this.layer.destroyFeatures([feature]);
                        } else {
                            feature.state = OpenLayers.State.DELETE;
                            this.layer.events.triggerEvent("afterfeaturemodified",
                                                       { feature: feature });
                            feature.renderIntent = "select";
                            this.layer.drawFeature(feature);
                        }
                    },
                    clickFeature: function (feature) {
                        // if feature doesn't have a fid, destroy it

                        if (feature.fid == undefined) {
                            this.layer.destroyFeatures([feature]);
                        } else {
                            feature.state = OpenLayers.State.DELETE;
                            this.layer.events.triggerEvent("afterfeaturemodified",
                                                       { feature: feature });
                            feature.renderIntent = "select";
                            this.layer.drawFeature(feature);
                        }
                    },
                    setMap: function (map) {
                        this.handler.setMap(map);
                        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.setMap.apply(this, arguments);
                    },
                    CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Control.DeleteFeature"
                }
```

);

Everythings is same with clickFeature. i wrote new function and i call it and i give this function feature which i stored. but i gave this error :Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'destroy' How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 draw.events.register("featureadded", this, function (e) {
                     alert(e.feature);
                     pointNumber = 1;
                     draw.deactivate();
                     noktasil(e.feature);
                 });
```

i wrote this codes and it's fine, works